# UIButton doesn't recognize touch on the lower half (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift3

I have an UIButton which doesn't recognize a touch on the lower half. 
[image: Layout]
[image: arrange]

[image: whole storyboard]

The view is yellow, "oben Balken1" is the green beam on the right side and "oben Balken2" is on the left side. "Person Label" is the red one and "Move Button" is the grey one in the middle. 
The UiView on the top side is "Events" and the UIView on the bot side is "Bot Container"

So I made the following test

```
@IBAction func clickedTEST(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Clicked")
}
```

It only print "Clicked" if I click on upper half of the UIButton.

The Debug View Hierarchy looks good too:
[image: Debug View Hierarchy]

I can't figure out the problem. I hope someone can help me!

Kindly Regards

User: 5859485

Comment: Is it possible that one of the superview is too high? So that the button is out of bounds to one of its superviews.

Comment: If I make a space between the UIView on the Botside to the View in the middle of 40 constraints I can click on the lower half. In the UIView is a TabBarControler. Maybe there is a problem with a navigationBar?